# expecting a right parentheses SOSL

Tags: sosl, dynamic-sosl

I am creating a dynamic SOSL which finally executed as below when I print in debug:

```
FIND 'gar,ont2' RETURNING Contact ( Name, FirstName, LastName  WHERE (Preferred_First_Name__c like '%gar%'   OR Preferred_Name_Concatenated__c like '%gar%'   OR ((MiddleName != null OR Two_First_Names__c = true OR Preferred_First_Name__c != null) AND Preferred_Name_Concatenated__c like '%gar%')   OR Login__c like '%gar%'   OR Employee_Id__c like '%gar%) AND Location_Building__c = 'ont2'  ORDER BY Name ASC LIMIT 201)
```

Error - `expecting a right parentheses, found 'ont2'`

Can any body help what is wrong with query?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a missing `'` character here:

```
OR Employee_Id__c like '%gar%)
```

Must be replaced by:

```
OR Employee_Id__c like '%gar%')
```